# Restrict inheritance depth

Tags: php, inheritance, restriction

I'm looking for a solution to restrict inheritance depth to one level in PHP. Similar to the 'friend' keyword in C++ I want to make sure that functionality of a specific class A could be used in class B, but not in class C which inherits from class B.
Did anyone already solve such a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Declare methods as [`final`](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.final.php) in class B to prevent class C from overriding or extending them.